# using the r melt function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, r

I have a data.frame in R that I’m transforming with the melt() function. Heres what the R code looks like

```
dat <- melt(data.frame, id="ORDER.TEST.MNEMONIC")
```

I’m trying to perform the same function with javascript on a object generated from a TSV file. I found this melt function on github [click here](https://github.com/jrideout/melt.js).

However I’m not sure how to use the javascript melt function to produce the same results as the above R code.

this javascript below can get the TSV file into an object. An than I want to melt this object.. but when i try

var melted = melt(obj)

it doesn’t give me what I’m expecting, or the same output I would expect with the R function. If someone has a better understanding of this javascript melt function and could reproduce the output that the R function creates that would be amazing.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        // check browser support
        // console.log(SimpleExcel.isSupportedBrowser);

        var fileInputCSV = document.getElementById('fileInputCSV');
        var file_name;
        // when local file loaded
        fileInputCSV.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

            // parse as TSV
            var file = e.target.files[0];
            file_name = file.name;
            console.log("file name", file_name);
            var csvParser = new SimpleExcel.Parser.TSV();
            csvParser.setDelimiter('\t');
            csvParser.loadFile(file, function () {

                // draw HTML table based on sheet data
                var sheet = csvParser.getSheet();
                var table = document.getElementById('result');
                var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
                table.innerHTML = "";
                sheet.forEach(function (el, i) {
                    var row = document.createElement('tr');
                    el.forEach(function (el, i) {
                        var cell = document.createElement('td');
                        cell.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
                        cell.setAttribute('id', 'cells');
                        cell.innerHTML = el.value;
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    });
                    table.appendChild(tbody);
                    tbody.appendChild(row);
                });

                var data = csvParser.getSheet(1);
                console.log("data", data);
                var melted = melt(data);
                // console.log("melted", melted);
                console.log("melted", JSON.stringify(melted,null));
                console.log("length", melted.length);
                // var json_data = JSON.stringify(data);


        });


    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Choose TSV file: </h3>
<input type="file" id="fileInputCSV" class="btn btn-default" style="border:2px dashed grey; height:50px; background-color:lightgrey; width:100%;"/><br/>
```

Comment: Describe the melt function, at least algorithmically. You're asking us to leave the site and delve into other code bases, that's something you have the ability to do yourself

Comment: Basically, you "melt" data so that each row is a unique id-variable combination. it's a function of the Hadley Wickham 'Reshape' package. http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html